# How can I capture the parameters from a report in the report in Axapta

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

How can I capture the parameters from a report in the report

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more explicit what your actual problem is.

Comment: Which version of AX?

Comment: Microsoft dynamics Axapta 2009

Comment: Hi   StephenKing                                                                                                                 I show the data in the report,In addition to queries from the selection screen to show by putting a few Gotta

Comment: What can I do with this method and code ?

Answer (score 1):

Take this answer for AX2012 and modify it for 2009 and your needs:

[how to get static range in your report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828505/how-to-get-static-range-in-your-report)

Comment: Thanks mrsalonen ,but it didn't

Comment: It didn't what? That is for AX2012, you can't use it as is, you have to modify it for AX2009, but the basics are the same.

Since you haven't specified why you need this, no one really knows what you want :)